# hibernate cannot get or delete by entity name

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate cannot find my entities by entity name, throwing an

```
IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: Study
```

I'm using Hibernate 5.2 with Java 8, and PostgeSQL9.4.

The class is defined as:

```
@Entity(name="Study")
@Table(name="STUDY")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class Study {
```

The query being executed is:

```
session.delete("Study", 96);
```

Similarly,

```
session.get("Study", 96);
```

fails, but

```
session.get(Study.class, 96);
```

succeeds.

I'm using the javax.persistence annotations on the Study class.

```
import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
...etc...
```

I have also tried deleting with the fully qualified class name as entity name with the same result.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is your application discovering your entities?

Comment: Try to use the full name of the class: something like this: `com.example.Study`. But it looks that your class was not registered in `SessionFactory`.

Comment: @sergey The class is registered. I can store and retrieve it using HQL. I have also tried using the full class name as mentioned above in the last line.

Comment: @neilos I don't understand the question.  The class is registered with the service factory using programmatic registration.